# Need to find you if the user is using magnified font size 125% or 150% in win 7

Tags: windows, winforms, font-size, magnification

Does anyone know if I can check this parameter anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read [`Graphics.DpiX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.dpix%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to discern this.

Multiply `Graphics.DpiX` by 100 and divide by 96 and you will have the percentage font scaling. This is true because 100% font scaling equates to 96dpi.

Be warned that if your application is not marked as [DPI aware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464660%28VS.85%29.aspx) then when the user sets font scaling to 150% the `DpiX` property will report 96. Off the top of my head I do not know whether or not standard WinForms apps are marked as DPI aware.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using C#, you need to do two steps to make this work in Windows 7.

First, make your application DPI-aware.  [This blog](http://www.rw-designer.com/DPI-aware) explains how to do that. It involves either modifying your application manifest, or calling the [SetProcessDPIAware()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (which may or may not exist).

Next, get the X/Y DPI values with `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX)` and `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY)`, respectively, as explained in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266.aspx).

I have an application that wasn't previously DPI aware, but still broke when used with text scaling (as available in the Windows 7 "Display" control panel), and this got it working, while having no effect on Windows 8 or newer.